# is there way to connect the two added tr in different table?

Tags: jquery

The problem of the code is I don't know a way to make the added tr same as the original tr that insert the value of the ITEM and QUANTITY into another table using the val() method.

the first table is the primary table where I inputted the value, and the second table is the secondary table were getting some of the value on the first table.
sample
firsttable
item  quantity  description
|  apple |      1     |    Sweet     |
|  orange |      1     |    Sweet    |
second table
|--item--|Quantity ety |  Quantity ext  | Balance qty | guard |  Datetime
|--apple--|------1------|---------------|--------1----|--------|-----------|
|--orange--|------1------|---------------|------1------|--------|-----------|
i want this program like this

```js
var $item = $('input[name ="Item"]')
var item = $("input[name^='Item']")
var $quantity = $('input[name ="Quantity"]')
var $desc = $('input[name ="Description"]')
var $item2 = $('input[name ="Item2"]')
var item2 = $("input[name^='Item2']")
var $qtyent = $('input[name ="Qtyent"]')
var $qtyext = $('input[name ="Qtyext"]')
var $balqty = $('input[name ="Balanceqty"]')
var $DOT = $('input[name ="DatenTime"]')
var $input = $('[name ="Item2"],[name ="Qtyent"],[name ="Qtyext"],[name ="Balanceqty"],[name="Guard"],[name="DatenTime"]')
var itemarray, item2array;
var seconditemarray;


$(document).on('change', "tbody.tbody td input.firsttable", function() {
  itemarray = [];
  item2array = [];

  $(".tbody tr").each(function(i, v) {

    itemarray[i] = $(this).find('input.firsttable').get()
      .map(function(input) {
        $item2.val($item.val())
        $balqty.val($quantity.val())
        $qtyent.val($quantity.val())
        return input.value

      });
  });
  $(".tablebody tr").each(function(j, k) {
    item2array[j] = $(this).find('input.secondtable').get()
      .map(function(input) {

        return input.value

      });
  });

  console.log(itemarray, item2array)

})
$(document).on('click', '.item-add-onclick', function() {
  var cols = "";
  var col = "";

  cols += `<tr><td>
                <input type="text" name="Item" class="firsttable" value required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="Quantity" class="firsttable" value required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Description" class="firsttable" value required>
            </td></tr>`;
  $('.tbody').append(cols);
  col += `<tr class="tablerow">
     <td>
         <input type="text" name="Item2" class="secondtable" id="item2" value disabled>
     </td>
     <td>
         <input type="number" name="Qtyent" class="secondtable" id="qtyent" value disabled>
     </td>
     <td>
         <input type="text" name="Qtyext" class="secondtable" id="qtyext" value required>
     </td>
     <td>
         <input type="number" name="Balanceqty" class="secondtable" id="blnqty" min="0" value  readonly>
     </td>
     <td>
         <input type="text" name="Guard" class="secondtable" id="GoD" value required>
     </td>
     <td>
         <input type="datetime-local" name="DatenTime" class="secondtable" id="DoT" value required>
     </td>
 </tr>`

  $('.tablebody').append(col)
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Description</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="Item" class="firsttable" id="item" value required>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="Quantity" class="firsttable" id="quantity" value required>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="Description" class="firsttable" id=desc value required>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-primary item-add-onclick" id="addrow">Add</button>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <Table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>Qty Enter</td>
        <td>Qty Exit</td>
        <td>Balance Qty</td>
        <td>Guard On Duty</td>
        <td>Date and Time</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tablebody">
      <tr class="tablerow">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="Item2" class="secondtable" id="item2" value disabled>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="Qtyent" class="secondtable" id="qtyent" value disabled>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="Qtyext" class="secondtable" id="qtyext" value required>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="Balanceqty" class="secondtable" id="blnqty" min="0" value readonly>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="Guard" class="secondtable" id="GoD" value required>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="datetime-local" name="DatenTime" class="secondtable" id="DoT" value required>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </Table>
</body>
<script src="table.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: every time i type on the first table it needs to auto insert to the second table and same as i added new row but i dont how to.

Comment: Is this helpful to you: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qvbyxjw3/ ? If it is, I can explain it in a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would like to use a templating library so as to avoid including all of that HTML markup in our JavaScript. I will go with [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/).

We will create two Handlebars templates: a row for each of our templates:

```
<script id="Table1RowTemplate" type="text/template">
  <tr>
    {{!-- Table 1 Row markup goes here --}}
  </tr>
</script>

<script id="Table2RowTemplate" type="text/template">
  <tr>
    {{!-- Table 2 Row markup goes here --}}
  </tr>
</script>
```

In the Table2 template, we will use an attribute, `[data-ref]`, on the input so that we know which input in Table1 it is linked to. For example `input[name="Item"]` in Table1 will be linked to `input[data-ref="Item"]` in Table2.

Now that we have these templates, we will remove the markup from our tables. We will use JavaScript to populate these tables on page load, using the templates we just defined.

The `<tbody></tbody>` elements in both tables will now be empty.

We will also give each table an ID for easy reference. We will go with "Table1" and "Table2".

In our JavaScript, we will define a function to append rows to our tables:

```
const table1RowTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Table1RowTemplate').innerHTML);

const table2RowTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('Table2RowTemplate').innerHTML);

const appendRows = () => {
  $('#Table1 tbody').append(table1RowTemplate());
  $('#Table2 tbody').append(table2RowTemplate());
};
```

And we can invoke this function to populate our tables with their first rows: `appendRows();`.

We will also use this function as the handler for a click of our `.item-add-onclick` button, so that clicking the button will add a row to each table:

```
$('.item-add-onclick').on('click', appendRows);
```

And finally the `change` handler:

```
// listen to input changes in #Table1
$('#Table1').on('change', 'input', function () {
  // get the input that was changed
  const $this = $(this);
  // get the name of the input
  const name = $this.attr('name');
  // get the new value of the input
  const value = $this.val();
  // get the index of the row of the input
  const index = $('#Table1').find(`input[name="${name}"]`).index($this);
  // get the corresponding row in #Table2 with the index
  const row = $('#Table2 tbody tr').get(index);
  
  // we have used an attribute, `data-ref`, to link the inputs in
  // Table2 to their partners in Table1 - the `[name]` in Table1
  // corresponds to the `[data-ref]` in Table2
  // so we can easily find the partner and update its value
  $(row).find(`input[data-ref="${name}"]`).val(value);
});
```

And here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qvbyxjw3/) for reference.

Comment: thank you, this code helps me and another question if I added a condition to this code i where I can insert the condition or just make another function my condition is on the table 2.

Comment: @tafreets What sort of condition?

Comment: if the balance qty value is equal to zero, the whole row dissable when the date change
else add row until the balancec qty is equal to zero

Comment: What does the balance qty represent? When does it get updated?

Comment: the balance qty same value from the quantity

Comment: @tafreets I'm not really sure what you mean about the date change, but maybe this can be a good starting point for you: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/14Lk6enm/

Comment: it disabled when the date change its value and subtraction quantity ext and balance qty the if there result is zero whole row disabled when the guard on duty and date and time has a value if the result is not zero it add a row until the balance qty is equal to zero.
just like this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319190/how-to-make-the-first-row-same-as-the-added-row-in-table-jquery

Comment: and im sorry for my english grammar

Comment: I'm sorry. There is a lot of pieces to this and I don't think I can understand them all. Maybe you need to open a new question.